# How to get price value with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to write a crawler for an Online Store and now I need to get the price value of the webpage. Here is my try:

```
$match = "";
$isMatched = preg_match('|<div class="c-product__seller-price-pure js-price-value".*\$(.*)<|',$html,$match);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
echo "</pre>";
```

Basically `$html` holds the source code of the webpage and the price value is stored at the document like this:

`<div class="c-product__seller-price-pure js-price-value">10,699,000</div>`

But when I run this I get this as result:

```
Array
(
)
```

Meaning that, the regular expression that I'm using is not correct:

`|<div class="c-product__seller-price-pure js-price-value".*\$(.*)<|`

So how can I get this price value with regex properly?

Comment: Hi tejoslaeslio. I notice you are adding copy+paste begging messages to every question. Please refrain from doing that - it creates a lot of work for volunteer editors. It may help for you to think of Stack Overflow as more like documentation, and less like a chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently matching any character `.*` after js-price-value" with a dollar sign `$. But there's no dollar sign in your source HTML.

Drop the `$` sign and match anything between the opening and closure of the tag.

Easiest way is to use the NOT operator `^`, to match any character that is not the `<` sign, like this `([^<]+)`

See below complete code:

```
$match = "";
$isMatched = preg_match('|c-product__seller-price-pure js-price-value">([^<]+)|', $html, $match);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
echo "</pre>";
```